# ifconfig and ip link show display different interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, debian, debian-stretch, iproute2

I've configured a `eno2` interface by mistake on Debian Stretch, now I've deleted it from `/etc/network/interfaces` and now is like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

# IPv6 interface
iface eno1 inet6 static
    address ****:****:****::1
    netmask 48
```

So, the `ifconfig` command show these interfaces:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:63:12:47:a0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet ***.***.***.***  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast ***.***.***.***
        inet6 ****:****:****::*  prefixlen 48  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe0e:c7ee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **:**:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1430101  bytes 213249567 (203.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3066573  bytes 4160098195 (3.8 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf120000-df13ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 950165  bytes 317274829 (302.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 950165  bytes 317274829 (302.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But the `ip link show` show the `eno2` interface also if it still no longer exists:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I tried to delete the non configured interface with the `ip link delete eno2`, but it returns the error `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`

How can I remove the `eno2` interface from `ip link show`?

---

**UPDATE:** the `ispconfig -a` command actually show the eno2 interface, but this nic doesn't exist physically in the system that's why I want delete it.

---

**UPDATE2:** output of `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 SoC Transaction Router (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at df180000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 1
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at df160000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: de000000-df0fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 2
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at df140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 PCIe Root Port 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:0e.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 RAS (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 RAS
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00

00:0f.0 IOMMU: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 RCEC (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 RCEC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Event Collector, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Root Complex Event Collector <?>

00:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 SMBus 2.0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 SMBus 2.0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at df1ab000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: ismt_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_ismt

00:14.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I354 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Ethernet Connection I354
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at df120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at e060 [size=32]
    Memory at df1a4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=10 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 0c-c4-7a-ff-ff-0e-c7-ee
    Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
    Capabilities: [1d0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb

00:14.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I354 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Ethernet Connection I354
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at e040 [size=32]
    Memory at df1a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=10 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 0c-c4-7a-ff-ff-0e-c7-ee
    Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
    Capabilities: [1d0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb

00:16.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at df1aa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:18.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 AHCI SATA3 Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 AHCI SATA3 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at e0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e020 [size=32]
    Memory at df1a9000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 PCU (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 PCU
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom processor C2000 PCU SMBus (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Atom processor C2000 PCU SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at df1a8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

02:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: de000000-df0fffff
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express PCI-Express to PCI/PCI-X Bridge, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a4] Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel modules: shpchp

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc ASPEED Graphics Family
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at df000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: ast
    Kernel modules: ast
```

Comment: [#Bug:1452868](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1452868) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it backwards: Hardware network interface aren’t *defined* in `/etc/network/interfaces`. They are detected by the kernel and are then available. If you don’t have them in `/etc/network/interfaces`, they will remain unused and in the “down” state.

`ifconfig` will, by default, only show interfaces that are “up”. If you want to see all interfaces, use `ifconfig -a`. You will then see `eno2`, which is currently down.

To remove `eno2`, you will need to physically remove it from the system.

Your dedicated server comes with a dual-port NIC. This is evident in `lspci`. Since it’s a dual-port NIC, you cannot remove the second port.

All Atom processors of the “Avoton” (C2000) family have at least 2 built-in Ethernet MACs.

Comment: But my system doesn't really have that interface: it's a dedicated server from online.net, with only 1 NIC. The eno2 interface configuration was added by mistake, and should not exists physically.

Comment: Please check the output of `dmesg` for information about network devices to verify. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225496) on how to determine which driver is “at fault”. Also, why not just ignore the interface? It most certainly won’t cause any harm. // Also, to clarify again: Unless you use special options in `interfaces`, a network interface *will not* be created. You wouldn’t use those options by mistake.

Comment: From a `dmesg` i don't have anything about the `eno2` interface except this: `[47961.911861] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno2: link is not ready`. The script shows that eno1 and eno2 are under the `igb` driver. I don't understand why it keep showing an non-existent and non-configured interface, thats why i want to delete that.

Comment: I’m telling you, it does exist. Please provide (in your question) the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Well, as you’ve surely found in the `lspci` output, you *do* have two network interfaces. I’ve updated my answer accordingly.